# adding 'if' logic to a jQuery chain

Tags: jquery, jquery-chaining

Let's say I have the following jQuery:

```
// pseudocode  :
$(this)
    .doSomething
    .doSomething
    .selectSomething
        .doSomething
        .animate({ 
            opacity: 1
        }, 150)
        .end()
    .selectSomethingElse
        .doSomething
```

I want the above to execute. However, if the browser is IE, I don't want the animate part to execute (due to IE being unable to animate objects with transparent PNGs and retain PNG transparency).

Is there anyway to maintain the nice chained jquery syntax but somehow skip the animate part based on some if logic (in this case testing for IE)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do an `each()` and pass a function to it which handles the animation, that should work.

```
$(this)
    .doSomething
    .doSomething
    .selectSomething
        .doSomething
        .each(function() {
            // Will return false on IE, true on others
            if(jQuery.support.opacity) {
                $(this).animate({ 
                    opacity: 1
                }, 150);
            }
        })        
    .end()
.selectSomethingElse
    .doSomething
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to filter out IE:

```
$(this).filter(function() {
    return $.support.opacity;
}).animate({ 
    opacity: 1
}, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a block of code before this which checks for IE and, if found, removes whatever selector the first ".selectSomething" is using.  Or, modify .selectSomething slightly so it checks an additional class that is only present in non-IE browsers.

It'd help keep your browser-detection logic separate.

Comment: Yea, inserting an extra class somewhere seems like an option, though requires more traversing within the jquery chain. I don't want to exclude the entire block, as I want all of it to execute regardless of browsers EXCEPT the one part of the chain.